# Can Subccategories be included in the menus directly?

Tags: magento

Hi I just want to know that how can i add Subccategories in the Navigation menus without making the parent category to show up there Any Ideas???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take quite a bit of surgery to make this happen in a programatic fashion.  You'll need to override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` method.

Alternatively, you might be able to hide the parent categories using your skin's CSS?  The `ul#nav li` elements have quite specific `class` and `id` values that should allow you to show or hide them.  However I suspect given the complexity of the fly-out nav, you may find it more efficient to rewrite the PHP.  It probably comes down to where your proficiency lies.

HTH,
JD

Comment: The child navs are contained by their parents, so the latter option may be just as messy. I would suggest structuring categories correctly as a significantly faster fix :)